# Making data save in uppercase with laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

When I am entering data on my form, I have set it to only enter uppercase letters however when saving, I see that it saves as a lowercase in the SQL DB. Is there any way to change this?

Heres my code:

controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
$energy = new Energy;
$energy->energyid = $request->input('energyid');
$energy->energydetail = $request->input('energydetail');
$energy->save();
return redirect('/page')->with('success', 'data added');
    }
```

Comment: use this php function - https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtoupper.asp

Comment: @Hamelraj where would it go though

Comment: `$energy->energyid = strtoupper($request->input('energyid'));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation hopefully it will solve your problem

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    '//your_field' => 'required|string|regex:/(^([A-Z]))/u'   
     ]);
        if ($validator->fails()){
            return "invalid data";
        }
else{
    $energy = new Energy;
    $energy->energyid = $request->input('energyid');
    $energy->energydetail = $request->input('energydetail');
    $energy->save();
    return redirect('/page')->with('success', 'data added');
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways with which you can achieve this, one is as mentioned by Doggo `$energy->energyid = strtoupper($request->input('energyid'));` and the other is creating a request file and using a package (https://github.com/Waavi/Sanitizer)

here is how your code will look like

```
class EnergyStoreRequest extends BaseFormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'energyid' => 'required',
            'energydetail' => 'required'
        ];
    }


    /**
     *  Filters to be applied to the input.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return [
            'energyid' => 'trim|uppercase',
        ];
    }

}
```

And your controller will look likt this

```
public function store(EnergyStoreRequest $request)
    {
      $input = $request->validated();
      $energy = new Energy;
      $energy->energyid = $input['energyid'];
      $energy->energydetail = $input['energydetail'];
      $energy->save();
      return redirect('/page')->with('success', 'data added');
    }
```